# Node.js + Discord.js - YouTube 24/7 Radio Voice Streaming

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, video-streaming, streaming

I've created a bot to stream in discord channel some youtube videos (only sound).
I'm using dispatcher to pause/ stop/ play some videos, but it wont play **youtube radio.**
When bot connecting to my channel with link to radio - it keeps playing only about 2-3 seconds and stops (and dispatcher not triggering by 'finish' event).
I've tested video with 15h. duration and all works fine, but 12h **livestreams** is a trouble for bot.

Nothing special in my code, I think, but anyways:

```
const connection = await client.channels.cache
  .find(channel => channel.name === musicVoiceChannelName).join();
        
dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(message.content.split(" ")[1], { filter: 'audioonly' }));
```

What should I do to play 24/7 livestreams on YouTube? Appreciate any thoughs.

Comment: For livestreams Youtube segments a video into small chunks of few seconds (_ie:_ some videos are 6 second pieces)... I don't use Discord so you tell me, does it play M3U8 files? Can it play a TS video file? My thoughts is just find an online radio station that streams in MP3 format. The Youtube part is over-complicated on purpose to avoid copyright issues. You can see they put a dummy 3 sec video to fool apps like YT-DL but the full media is an M3U8 file.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of youtube live stream, using the audioonly option will not succeed.
I don't know further details, but anyway, if you remove the audioonly option, it will play.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).